# The relation between minimal prime ideals and nilpotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Show that a prime ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is minimal if and only if for each $x\in I$ there exists $a\in R\setminus I$ such that $ax$ is nilpotent.

Comment: You used $I$ to denote a prime ideal then used $P.$ Also, a prime ideal that is a minimal ideal may not be a minimal prime ideal. Can you be more precise with your problem statement?

Comment: Dear @Ragib, If a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal ideal, i.e. minimal among all ideals, then in particular it is also minimal among all prime ideals, so it is a minimal prime.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Sorry I meant to say a minimal prime ideal may not be a minimal ideal. Being a prime ideal that is minimal is strictly stronger than being a minimal prime ideal.

Answer (score 2):

If $I$ is minimal, localize at $I$ to see $I R_I$ is nilpotent in $R_I$, which implies some power of $x\in I$ is annihilated in $R$ by some $a\notin I$. In this case, $ax$ is certainly also nilpotent in $R$.

If $I$ is not minimal, then there is some smaller prime ideal $I'\subset I$. For $x\in I\setminus I'$ the assumption then gives some $a\notin I$ with $ax$ nilpotent; since $I'$ is prime and $x\notin I'$, this implies $a\in I'$, contradicting $a\notin I$.